# How to iterate through invidiual items in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iteration

I have 3 individual objects like `user`,`data`,`auth`. Each object has to go through a same function like `deleteById` as below

```js
deleteById(user, user.table) ;
deleteById(data, data.table);
deleteById(auth, auth.table);
```

But what I am trying to do is, something similar to below `python` code

```py
for obj in user, data, auth:
  deleteById(obj, obj.table)
```

How can I achieve this in JavaScript ?
Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
for (var obj of [user, data, auth]) {
    deleteById(obj, obj.table);
}

// or
[user, data, auth].forEach(obj => deleteById(obj, obj.table));
```

Comment: Accepting this answer, as both are same but you answered 9 seconds early. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You could take an array and iterate the objects.

```
for (let obj of [user, data, auth])
    deleteById(obj, obj.table);
```